# Trying to find this transformer or one similar. Stated 50mH 450:10:10

Tags: mosfet, transformer

50mH 450:10:10 Type 147

Type 147 whatever that means. The circuit is for a 2 phase high voltage high frequency motor. My questions are:

What type of transformer is this?

What footprint is it?

What are the DNM caps for?

There are two coils on the input, surely a H-bridge would mitigate the need for two coils, what do you think the designer was thinking?

Here's some images of what I'm trying to identify:

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]
[image: Image3]

Comment: Have you seen a transformer like this before?

Comment: Is this a 2 phase VFD? I've been meaning to build a 2 phase VFD for ages now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Seen like", yes. It's a low profile E style core (ELP, ER, etc.), on an SMT bobbin.  A similar part that comes to mind is Coilcraft's Hexa-Path series (however, they do not offer such a high ratio as these parts, evidently).

The windings can be anything of course; custom transformers are quite common, when you're going to the trouble of using a transformer at all.  Off-the-shelf transformers are mainly convenient for design, prototyping and early production purposes; they can often be purchased cheaper from local custom manufacturers.  So there isn't a whole lot to read into the markings.  The inductance and turns ratio (among other parameters) are the important characteristics, and fortunately not too hard to measure.

Push-pull (the split primary) is more common at low voltages, and trades the bother of four MOSFETs and two half-bridge drivers for two MOSFETs and potentially no drivers (logic-level MOSFETs are available).

The arrangement is less common at high voltages, where the added cost of a dual driver is worth the reduced losses from eliminating the tapped winding (namely, the leakage inductance between ends).  Or at low power levels, a single switch might be used (e.g. flyback converter).

It's not clear why there are two, but given the description, they may be driven in quadrature to generate phase-shifted output to drive the motor.  To be clear, each transformer is driven with 180° phase shifted inputs, but 90° between the two transformers.  So the transistors would be driven (from top to bottom) at 0, 180, 90 and 270° respectively, say.

Presumably, the duty cycle of each gate signal is a bit below 50% as well, as this prevents shoot-through (both transistors potentially being on at the same time means effectively shorting out the supply for a brief instant).

Answer (score 1):

The transformers allow the outputs to be driven with a simple push-pull arrangement rather than a complex H-bridge. Given the common output connection you'd need +/- high voltage supplies and an H-bridge for each coil. From the sin/cos markings, it appears they are driven in quadrature.

Not incidentally, they also give a +/-45:1 step-up in voltage relative to Vs, allowing the use of relatively low voltage low Rds(on) MOSFETs.

The transformers are surely custom made for the application, though the bobbin and core will be standard. Judging by the construction the voltage is not *really* high, hundreds of volts, maybe?

One potential issue with push-pull driven transformers is flux buildup due to slight mismatch in the drives, which can lead to catastrophic failure.

Comment: How would you avoid the flux buildup?

Comment: @Betpro ti.com/lit/an/slyt813/slyt813.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The caps marked "DNM" on the schematic also have no values. This leads me to think that DNM stands for Do Not Mount, i.e., do not install the parts on the PCB. Also known as DNF for Do Not Fit. So they were intended as placeholders for capacitors, but were not needed in the final version.